# How to build ld.so alone?

Tags: linux, glibc

I know that ld.so belongs to glibc, and I want to modify the source code of it and build it alone. But building entire glibc is too much heavy, and the makefiles are so complicated that I just don't know where to start digging out. Any tips?

Comment: You might try asking on `libc-help@sourceware.org`. This is not likely to help -- my suspicion is that you will have to suck it up and build the whole thing -- but it doesn't cost much to ask.

Comment: thanks for you reply, I tried sending a email to them but it failed all time and it said that i'm not using plain text

Answer (score 5):

> I want to modify the source code of it and build it alone

If you did `./configure; make` in the source directory (i.e. you are not using a separate build directory), then:

```
make -C elf
```

will rebuild `ld.so`. If you build in a separate directory, e.g. in `/tmp/build` while your source is in `$HOME/glibc-src`, then:

```
cd /tmp/build; make -C $HOME/glibc-src/elf objdir=`pwd`
```

If you have a reasonably powerful machine, `make -j16 ...` may work even better.